# JPA direct join to entities with common primary key

Tags: java, jpa

Assume I have dozen of one-to-one relation using common id `carId` and **I can't touch schema or merge them into one**.

```java
@Entity
public class Car {
  @Id
  private Integer id;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy="car")  
  private Registration regist;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy="car")  
  private Detail detail;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy="car")  
  private License license;
}

@Entity
public class Registration {
  @OneToOne
  private Car car;

  private String governor;
}

@Entity
public class Detail {
  @OneToOne
  private Car car;

  private Date manufacturingDate;
}

@Entity
public class License {
  @OneToOne
  private Car car;

  private String licenseNumber;
}

// and more ...
```

When I create a query begin with `License` to get data from `Detail` and `Registration`, the generated sql looks like

```sql
select
    car_detail.manufacturing_date,
    car_registration.governor
from
    car_license
left outer join
    car
        on car_license.car_id=car.id
left outer join
    car_detail
        on car.id=car_detail.car_id
left outer join
    car
        on car_license.car_id=car.id
left outer join
    car_registration
        on car.id=car_registration.car_id
where
    and car_license.licenseNumber=?
```

It's reasonable because JPA doesn't understand column `car_id` is common across entities. However, the result is hard to debug and error prone on complicated join.

How can I define those entities so that JPA knowns they don't need additional join on table `car` and can be joined directly, or just join to table `car` only once?

Comment: Using `@SecondaryTable` to map multiple tables to one entity or using a view would make this a lot easier. Not sure if there is another solution.

Comment: Map car_id as a basic string in the entities (as well as as a OneToOne with car if you'd like, just make one read-only). You can then use that mapping string mapping in your joins without having to go through the car entity/table join to do so. "select d.manufacturingDate, r.governor from License l LEFT JOIN Detail d ON l.carId = d.carId LEFT JOIN Registration r ON l.carId = r.carId where l.licenseNumber = :number". This is supported in some JPA providers (EclipseLink) but if not, you can do the joins in the where clause instead.

Comment: though it looks like you have car in there twice, both being joined to car_license. If that is the issue/question - show the query that generated this. You should be able to write the query differently to avoid this extra, unnecessary join and use this model. Just make a query based off of car directly. "Select d.manufacturingDate, r.governor from Car c left join c.regist r left join c.detail d left join c.license l where l.licenseNumber = :number"